# how to get name of drawable of an imageview

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to get the name of background image of an imageview, but my code is showing the id of the imageview.

```
ListView lst = list.get(0);
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) lst.getChildAt(i);
ImageView imgV = (ImageView) view.getChildAt(1);
String checkBoxBtn = imgV.getResources().getResourceEntryName(imgV.getId()).toString();
```

please help

Comment: If you really need to keep some extra value in ImageView, just create your own ImageView which will inheritance form ImageView and add your variables. Remember also to change xml file if it needed.

Comment: you can use setTag("image name") and for the same image you can use getTag();

Answer (score 0):

The name isn't stored. You have to store it in a variable.